# SQL orcl10g trigger insert (deathDate after birthDate)

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle10g

The trigger needs to stop a death date before the birthdate being entered.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Check_deathDate
BEFORE INSERT Or UPDATE of deathDate on Actor
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
deathDate           DATE;
birthDate           DATE;
deathDate_Error     EXCEPTION;
IF (deathDate < birthDate) THEN
RAISE deathDate_Error;
END IF;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN deathDate_Error THEN
Raise_application_error( 'deathDate' || 'should be before' || 'birthDate');
END;);
```

gives error...

*
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification

...how else can i specifiy the IF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Check_deathDate
BEFORE INSERT Or UPDATE of deathDate, birthDate on Actor
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.deathDate < :NEW.birthDate) THEN
        Raise_application_error(-20000, 'deathDate should be before birthDate');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use a check constraint instead of a trigger.  Constraints are less powerful than triggers, but they are usually simpler and faster.

```
alter table actor add
constraint actor_birth_before_death check (birthDate <= deathDate);
```

Comment: +1, a much better approach than a trigger (thanks for the edit btw)